# Can not establish the connection by network developer

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have installed ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER on my WINDOWS 10 machine but for some reasons i can not connect a new connection. 
The error says that **Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**

I am attaching the photo of the error as well. Please have a look and guide me. Thanks. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8K9a.jpg)

Comment: This sounds like a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you have Oracle XE installed on your PC? SQL Developer is a client, you need a separate database server installation to connect to.

Comment: I wrote this just for you https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303